# Playing Audio After Amount Of Time Has Passed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a cutscene in unity, and I need to make audio play 2 seconds after another audio clip has passed. How could I do this?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class ButtonActionHolder : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioSource source;
    public AudioClip drnefariotalk1;
    public AudioClip childtalk;
    public AudioSource AudioSource;
    public AudioClip drnefariotalk2;

    IEnumerator Timer()
            {
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(31f);
                source.PlayOneShot(childtalk);
            }
    
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Timer());
    }
    
    public void Play()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean has passed? That it ends? I think a possible solution would be this:

```
IEnumerator Timer()
            {
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(31f);
                source.PlayOneShot(childtalk);
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(childtalk.length+2f);
                source.PlayOneShot(drnefariotalk1)
            }
```

Try this option if the previous one does't work. Basically this stay in the while loop while the audio is playing, when it stops start a timer and after that will play the second audioclip:

```
source.PlayOneShot(audioclip1);
while(source.isPlaying()) {
   yield return null
} 
yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
source.PlayOneShot(audioclip2);
```

Comment: I'm having a problem where it doesn't wait the amount of time that I set before playing the audio do you know how I could fix that?

Comment: Can you post a complete example of not working code?

Comment: Code exceeds limit of comment so here's a pastebin link: https://pastebin.com/zng873T1

Comment: Try this `source.PlayOneShot(audioclip1) while(source.isPlaying()) {yield return null} yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f) source.PlayOneShot(audioclip2)`

Comment: It keeps telling me that I'm missing a semicolon somewhere and It's confusing so can you make a pastebin paste and send me the link with the semicolons? https://pastebin.com

Comment: I modified my anwer. Try to check if it helps.